# Como substituir uma letra da string quando está mascarada?

Tags: java, string

Estou criando um jogo da forca para maior aprendizado da lógica de programação.

1- Eu mascarei o `textfield` com `***` para que o usuário não consiga ver a palavra.

2- No meu exemplo, eu criei **3 botões**, sendo respectivamente `"A", "B" e "C"`.

Vamos supor que a palavra a ser adivinhada seja `"mara"`, quando eu clico no botão `"A"`, **eu consigo encontrar a posição da letra a na String**. Elas se encontram na `posição 2 e 4`. Como o texto está mascarado com `"*"`, quando eu clico no botão `"A"`, eu gostaria que o `jtextfield` apresentasse todas as letras `"A"`.

Ficaria assim:

**Exemplo:** `*a*a`

> Porém, eu não estou conseguindo entender como fazer para mostrar
>   apenas essas letras.

Segue o código do meu exemplo simples verificável:

```
String p;
int tamanho;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public Principal() {
    initComponents();

    jba.addActionListener(this);
    jbb.addActionListener(this);
    jbc.addActionListener(this);

    System.out.println("Digite uma palavra: ");
    p = input.nextLine();

    String replaceP = p.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "*");

    jTextFieldPalavra.setText(replaceP);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    int tamanho = p.length();

    if(ae.getSource() == jba) {


    for(int i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {

        if(p.substring(i, i+1).equals("a")) {
            int posicao = i+1;
            System.out.println("Está na posição " + posicao);      

            //System.out.println(p.substring(0, posicao));

        } 

    }

    } else if(ae.getSource() == jbb) {

        for(int i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {

        if(p.substring(i, i+1).equals("b")) {
            int posicao = i+1;
            System.out.println("Está na posição " + posicao); 
            //System.out.println(p.substring(0, posicao));

        } 

    }


    } else if(ae.getSource() == jbc) {

        for(int i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {

        if(p.substring(i, i+1).equals("c")) {
            int posicao = i+1;
            System.out.println("Está na posição " + posicao); 
            //System.out.println(p.substring(0, posicao));

        } 

    }

    }

}
```

Nesse momento eu já cliquei no botão "A".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode adicionar um **[mcve]** deste seu código? Acho que da pra aplicar Document nele.

Comment: Então, esse seria o exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável que criei rs. Mas vou tentar representar melhor de acordo com o link que me mandou. ;)

Comment: O código não é executavel, tente copiar e salvar como .java e executar pra você ver. De qualquer forma, olha o que achei em outro site da SE, o mesmo jogo, veja se consegue entender a lógica http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82440/hangman-program-in-java

Comment: Entendi, não me atentei a isso. Obrigada, eu vou ler e tentar entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É muito simples utilizando o método [setCharAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,%20char)) do [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Eu criei um exemplo pra ilustrar (Pode copiar tudo e rodar):

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public JPanel contentPane;
    public JTextField textField;
    public String secretWord;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame f = new MainFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainFrame() {
        super("Jogo da Forca");
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        this.contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(this.contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[50px,grow][50px,grow][50px,grow]", "[50px,grow][50px,grow][50px,grow][50px,grow][50px,grow][50px,grow]"));

        textField = new JTextField();
        contentPane.add(textField, "cell 1 1,grow");
        textField.setColumns(10);
        this.secretWord = "MARA";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.secretWord.length(); i++) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "*");
        }

        JButton btnA = new JButton("A");
        contentPane.add(btnA, "cell 0 3,grow");
        JButton btnB = new JButton("B");
        contentPane.add(btnB, "cell 1 3,grow");
        JButton btnC = new JButton("C");
        contentPane.add(btnC, "cell 2 3,grow");
        JButton[] buttons = {btnA, btnB, btnC};
        for (JButton b : buttons) {
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String letter = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
                    String textFieldString = textField.getText();
                    StringBuilder replacement = new StringBuilder(textFieldString);
                    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
                        if (letter.equals(String.valueOf(secretWord.charAt(i))) && String.valueOf(textFieldString.charAt(i)).equals("*")) {
                            replacement.setCharAt(i, letter.charAt(0));
                            textField.setText(replacement.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Como pode ver, eu itero sobre a "palavra secreta" (`this.secretWord`), testo se a letra do botão apertado corresponde a algum caractere da mesma e checo se na posição do mesmo no campo de texto encontra-se um asterisco. Se verdadeiro, eu substituo o char em questão pela letra do botão, utilizando o StringBuilder (Que por sua vez utiliza da String do textField). Anyway, explicar em Português faz parecer mais difícil do que é. Estude o meu exemplo e o StringBuilder, que entenderá como adaptar para o seu código rs..